# Does Python dictionary ".values()" return the list in a particular order? [Python 2]

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm using a dictionary in Python 2, and am wondering if the dictionary.values() returns a list of values in a particular order

i.e. the order they were given into the dictionary in?

Example

```
dict = {}
dict[1] = "potato"
dict[2] = "tomato"
dict[3] = "orange"
dict[4] = "carrot"
list_val = dict.values()
```

Is list_val in the order `potato->tomato->orange->carrot`?
or is it in some other order?

This is a simple example, I mean will it return in the same order for even more complex structures?

For example, replace the strings with dictionaries
making it a dictionary of dictionaries

**NOTE: This was answered in the other thread, which is [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526125/why-is-python-ordering-my-dictionary-like-so)**

Another good answer to refer to for conceptual answer is :
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917590/why-are-python-dictionaries-not-stored-in-the-order-they-were-created?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: print list_val and find out?

Comment: did you tried it ?..

Comment: I'm wondering if this changes with more complex data
Simple strings might be in order
but something like list instead of "potato"?

Comment: It seems you have an underlying question which is not only if this example works but if you can rely in this property for other cases. I suggest you look at other question which are connected to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956313/why-is-dictionary-ordering-non-deterministic

Comment: Guys, the example with the veggies is *just an example*. The questioner is asking about general properties they can rely on, not what happens in this particular example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is python ordering my dictionary like so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526125/why-is-python-ordering-my-dictionary-like-so)

Comment: By now, there are several useful links in the right-hand sidebar (see the "Linked" section). None of them are *above* where you said "This was answered in the other thread, which is linked above". ;)

Comment: John, I'm referring to the "this question may have already been answered"

I think most readers would understand

Comment: this is a great question, and I really wish there was a good answer. It seems like the answer might be "no" but nobody's willing to say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

After reading some documentation on hash tables (what dict in python use to store `key` information) I found that the order in which you assign keys/values is not what defines its location in the has table. There is a really good video [HERE](http://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2010/the-mighty-dictionary-55.html) that does a great job of explaining how a hash table works and what is going on during the key assignment to the hash table.

Basically a key is assigned a hash number that is then placed in the hash table according to its hash number rather than its key value. This hash number is placed first in the desired location on the hash table that corresponds with its hash number unless there is already something assigned to that location. If something else is already assigned to that location on the Hash Table then python does some calculations to chose the next best location. This can be before or after the desired location in the has table. [HERE](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/) Is some documentation but I highly recommend watching the video I liked as it does a great job explaining this concept.

Comment: best not rely on order preservation of a standard `dict` object. If you must rely on order, use `OrderedDict` type.

Comment: @DavidZemens: I have never had a problem with the order of the dict remaining the same after it has been assigned. Why would it change?

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526125/why-is-python-ordering-my-dictionary-like-so) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary) for some discussion.

Comment: for example, when I do `d={'a':'A','b':'B','c':3,'d':4}` and then print I get: `{'a': 'A', 'c': 3, 'b': 'B', 'd': 4}`. if I then assign `d['e']=5` and print, I get: `{'a': 'A', 'c': 3, 'b': 'B', 'e': 5, 'd': 4}`!  Not all dicts are created by individual item assignment, consider comprehension etc., but also note the warnings built in that the *order* while should be consistent, should not be relied on :)

Comment: @DavidZemens: I am getting that from the documentation. I did not realize that the way the data is read derives from the hash table rather than the index of the dict. I will update my answer soon when I have finished reading the documentation.

Comment: @DavidZemens: I updated my answer. The video I found on one of the post you linked was really good at explaining hash tables in python so I added that into my answer as well. Thanks for letting me know about the post.